# Why aren't my pieces rotating on my chess board in Java?

Tags: java

I am developing chess game in Java using the Netbeans IDE. Instead of rotating the whole board at each move, I thought of changing position of the pieces themselves, while the board remains same. All my pieces and squares are `JLabel`s and are in a `JLayeredPane`, with pieces being in top layer. All the squares are part of a `JLabel` array named `labels` and same for white and black pieces.

`WinitialLocation` and `BinitialLocation` are Point Arrays for initial positions of white and black pieces.

But running the following code in `mouseReleased()` event of the pieces, only the piece which we moved changes place, the rest remain at their position.

Can anybody help me, Please?

```
void reLocate() {
     for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
     {
        for(int j=0, n=labels.length; j<n;j++)
        {
            if(labels[j].getLocation().equals(WinitialLocation[i]))
               wPieces[i].setLocation(labels[63-j].getLocation());

            if(labels[j].getLocation().equals(BinitialLocation[i]))
               bPieces[i].setLocation(labels[63-j].getLocation());
        }

        layer.moveToFront(wPieces[i]);
        layer.moveToFront(bPieces[i]);
    }
}
```